# Change Input type HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

`<input type="password">` I want to run a JavaScript snippet that changes “password” to “text” is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with pure Javascript or jQuery.

Let's assume your input is

```
<input type="password" id="input1"/>
```

Pure Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('input1').setAttribute('type', 'text');
```

jQuery:

```
$('#input1').attr('type', 'text');
```

Answer (score 1):

First give the input element a unique 'id'.

```html
<input type='password' id='uniqueId'>
```

Then access the input element using javascript to change the input type.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('uniqueId')
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option as an extra:

```
document.getElementById("id").type="text";
```